# Android hidden activity async calls

Tags: android, android-library

I am new to android and I am building an Android library where I have a weird use case like the following:

```
Method(parms...){
   if(somedata exists in local filestore)
      make webservice call and set result;
   else
      start activity with webview and get result from activity
   }
}
```

If the first condition succeeds I would like it to make the webservice call asynchronously, while with the second, an activity is invoked which I think needs to be on the same thread to allow the caller to get the activity result.

I was thinking to use a hidden activity like the one found [here](http://derekreynolds.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/creating-an-android-activity-with-no-ui/).  But it seems very hacky to me.  Any other suggestions?  I am thinking it might just be cleaner to have two separate methods in the library but I would like to keep them together if possible.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do with the activity containing the webview?  Is it just that you need to make an http call to get that data?

Comment: A user needs to enter information in the webview.  It has to be a webview too otherwise I could build a dialogue. They should only have to interact with the webview the first time or if the data is cleared in the app.

Answer (score 0):

An Activity without UI, do you mean a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)? Please read this document. It describes how to do synchronous and async calls to this service.

Comment: If I make the library a service can I surface UI by starting an activity? Then when the activity completes it will return to the service and then I can return to the caller via a handle passed in?